# need help in mvvmcross windows phone 8 fluent binding with conversion

Tags: windows-phone-8, binding, mvvmcross, fluent, valueconverter

I'm Little stuck in getting the fluent binding/conversion to Work. I have the following to work

```
set.Bind(TextBackStartColor).For(v => v.Text).To(vm => vm.TextBackStartColor).TwoWay()
```

but when I try to add a WithConversion, I need some help in how to get the converter called

```
set.Bind(TextBackStartColor).For(v => v.Text).To(vm => vm.TextBackStartColor).TwoWay().WithConversion("Test")
```

In xaml the converter works fine, in Android and Touch the above converter works fine.

I've tried in 
CORE:

```
public sealed class TestValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<string, string>
{
  protected override string Convert(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
    string test = (string)value + "test";

    return test;
  }

  public string ConvertBack(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return value;
  }
}
```

and the corresponding Phone/NativeConverters:

```
namespace DCS.Phone.NativeConverters
{
  public class NativeTestValueConverter : MvxNativeValueConverter<TestValueConverter>
  {
  }
}
```

I've also tried in 
Phone/Converters

```
public sealed class TestConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    string test = (string)value+"test";

    return test;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

But my converters are never getting called.
As I said my bindings works very well, so what am I missing in Phone project to get the converters called?

Answer (score 1):

Android and iOS both automatically pick up the ValueConverter names - the mechanism they do this by is described in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters#referencing-value-converters-in-touch-and-droid

Windows platforms don't do this by default - because Windows uses Xaml binding by default.

If you want to add this use of named value converters, then you can do this using code in your Windows Setup.cs like:

```
       // call this in InitializeLastChance
       Mvx.CallbackWhenRegistered<IMvxValueConverterRegistry>(FillValueConverters);

       // add this method
       private FillValueConverters(IMvxValueConverterRegistry registry)
       {
            registry.Fill(ValueConverterAssemblies);
       }

       // add this property
       protected virtual List<Assembly> ValueConverterAssemblies
       {
            get
            {
                var toReturn = new List<Assembly>();
                toReturn.AddRange(GetViewModelAssemblies());
                toReturn.AddRange(GetViewAssemblies());
                return toReturn;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hey Stuart, many thanks for Your, as always, quick answer. This helped getting the CORE converters, but not the native/device converters, and how do I get to the buildin/plugin converters such as Mvx Color ValueConverters ?

Comment: Got the buildin/plugin Mvx Color ValueConverters to Work, referenced the mvvmcross Color plugin. Thanks Again.